# ADFS 2012 R2 default Claims provider

Tags: adfs, claims

We have and ADFS 2012 R2 platform running with an external claims provider as well as Active Directory claims provider.
The setup works fine for logging into Office 365, where the user have to select the either of the Claims provider first time.
The issue is that when they try to edit a file from SharePoint online in word, they get prompted for login again, and here it will only accept the password stored in Active Directory, witch for some users is different from the password stored at the other Claims provider.

At the moment it is not possibly to sync the passwords due to external system limitations.

Is it possibly to get this working or to disable the extra prompt in SharePoint online?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want o365 to be accessed using the "active directory" claims provider only (adfs does the auth itself). The problem appears to be end user confusion as to what to provide when prompted for creds.

You can run set-adfsrelyingpartytrust as shown in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280950.aspx . Set the claims provider string array to "Active Directory" only to prevent prompts for credentials to any other idp.